# Should I document parameters for similar function signatures?

Tags: python, parameters, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

I have some helper functions that, except for the first argument, take the same arguments as the core function. The parameters are thoroughly documented in the core function. Should I copy-paste this documentation to the helper function too, or rather just point to the core documentation?

It that matters, I primarily intend my API reference to be read as HTML generated by Sphinx, and I use the numpydoc style. I didn't find an answer in the [numpydoc manual](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

### EDIT

Here is an MWE:

```py
def core(param0, param1=3, param2=8):
    """Core function with thorough documentation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    param0 : ndarray
        Description.
    param1 : int
        Long description.
    param2 : int
        Long description.

    Returns
    -------
    param_out : ndarray
        Long description

    """
    pass
```

```py
def helper(param3, param1=3, param2=8):
    """Helper function.

    """
    pass
```

As you can see, only the first parameter differs in the two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best, and easiest, way to do this is using [Python Sphinx docstring sections](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#docstring-sections) from the **`sphinx.ext.napoleon`** extension.

Only arguments unique to the *helper function* need to be explicitly documented, you can [remit with a cross-reference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) to the function/method defining the shared parameters. The *[Google style guide for Python](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#383-functions-and-methods)* advises the same reasoning for overloading inherited methods from a base class :

> A method that overrides a method from a base class may have a simple docstring sending the reader to its overridden method’s docstring, such as """See base class.""". **The rationale is that there is no need to repeat in many places documentation that is already present in the base method’s docstring.** However, if the overriding method’s behavior is substantially different from the overridden method, or details need to be provided (e.g., documenting additional side effects), a docstring with at least those differences is required on the overriding method.
>
> - Args:
>
>   List each parameter by name. A description should follow the name, and be separated by a colon and a space.

The following example:

```py
def core(param0, param1=3, param2=8):
    """Core function with thorough documentation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    param0 : ndarray
        Description.
    param1 : int
        Long description.
    param2 : int
        Long description.

    Returns
    -------
    param_out : ndarray
        Long description

    """
    pass

def helper(param3, param1=3, param2=8):
    """Remaining

    Parameters
    ----------
    param3 : int
        Description.
    Other Parameters
        A short string remitting reader to :py:func:`core` function.
    See Also
        A short string remitting reader to :py:func:`core` function.
    Note
        A short string remitting reader to :py:func:`core` function.
    """
    pass
```

Would give this result:

[image]

Comment: According to [numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) (see item 8), the other parameters should have a distinct section. What do you think about [this solution](https://imgur.com/a/U0pnNP8)?

Comment: Both our solutions used "distinct docstring sections". You used "rtd theme" while I used "alabaster theme", only the HTML is rendered differently (it seems "the sections aren't distinct" in my case, but in fact they are). I think your solution is the same, the difference being I didn't explicitly write the parameters in the "Other Parameters" section, because if you have long signatures (say 20 parameters, with 5 helper functions) it's more concise not to repeat the parameters every time (which in essence is what you're trying to avoid...)

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti note I also suggested 3 possible sections that can be used, together if necessary. The style guides omit what to do exactly, most folks don't use the "summary" sections to have 1 less word repeating in their documentation...